# node-oracledb - Bulk insert using associative array

Tags: node.js, oracle, plsql, node-oracledb

Im using node-oracledb driver in my nodeJs application. I am having to do bulk inserts (upto 6000 rows) and the batch insert feature of [simple-oracledb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-oracledb) extension did not meet my needs. It is painfully slow for 6000 records. I came across this [post](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:9526345800346872047) and [this doc](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#plsqlindexbybinds) from node-oracledb however and it seems like a promising way. It's just that im new to PL/SQL that Im not understanding how to do it.

So consider I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE 
( "CID" NUMBER,
"EMPID" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE));
```

I have 3 records for bulk insertion. Here is my PL/SQL package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MY_PKG IS
  TYPE cidtype IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  TYPE empidtype IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10);
  PROCEDURE insertproc(cids IN cidtype, empids IN empidtype);
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MY_PKG IS

  PROCEDURE insertproc(cids IN cidtype, empids IN empidtype) IS
  BEGIN
    FORALL i IN INDICES OF cids
      INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (cid, empid) VALUES (cids(i), empids(i));
  END;

END;
/
```

My NodeJS code:

```
var stmt = `BEGIN MY_PKG.insertproc(:cids, :empids); END;`;
var params = {
    cids: {
        type: oracledb.NUMBER,
        dir: oracledb.BIND_IN,
        val: [100, 101, 102]
    },
    empids: {
        type: oracledb.STRING,
        dir: oracledb.BIND_IN,
        val: ['ab165634', 'df123456', 'cd456789']
    }
};

connection.execute(stmt,params,function (err) { . . . });
```

However this throws the following error:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INSERTPROC'\nORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored\n
```

Since the example only show how u can bind array for 1 column, I couldnt figure out how its done for multiple columns (the entire row). Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: `TYPE cidtype IS TABLE OF MY_TABLE.CID%TYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  TYPE empidtype IS TABLE OF MY_TABLE.EMPID%TYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;`

Answer (score 1):

```
var sql = "insert into employee(id,name) values (:1,:2)";
var content = [];
for(i=0;i<data.length.i++)
{
var temp = [];
temp.push(data[i].id);
temp.push(data[i].name);
content.push(temp);
}

connection.executeMany(sql,content,function(err,result)
{
   if(err)
   console.log(err);
   else
   console.log("Success");
});
```

Comment: If you change the SQL to `... values (:id, :name)`, and your `data` array only has `id and `name` attributes, then you don't need to construct the `content` array - you can use `connection.executeMany(sql, data, ...`.  You may want to use `let` and `const` instead of the old `var` syntax.  And also look at using async/await instead of callbacks.  See [node-oracledb examples](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples).

Answer (score 0):

I talk a bit [about this here](https://jsao.io/2017/01/plsql-record-types-and-the-node-js-driver/), but really I need to have more examples...

Your code will work if you add the "INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER" to your empidtype type. That changes it from a nested table to an associative array, which is what the driver can currently bind to.

Here's a similar question I answered: [How to insert multiple records into oracle db using node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569126/how-to-insert-multiple-records-into-oracle-db-using-node-js/45572158#45572158)

And another that demonstrates how to do this in batches (second example): [Node.js + OracleDb - Insert the last date many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928986/node-js-oracledb-insert-the-last-date-many-times/42955490#42955490)

The batching would be much easier now [with async/await](https://jsao.io/2017/07/how-to-get-use-and-close-a-db-connection-using-async-functions/).

Finally (I promise), you might find these slide interesting:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/69jt5uu1fqus84c/Tips%20and%20Tricks%20for%20Getting%20Started%20with%20the%20Oracle%20Database%20Driver%20for%20Node.pdf?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Node-oracledb 2.2 introduces [connection.executeMany()](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#executemany) (also see [Batch Statement Execution](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#batchexecution)) making batch data insert more efficient.