# How to insert a Table Type in Oracle DB using node js

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I have procedure that will insert the values in Table .It has input parameter table type. I am trying to pass it as an object in binds but it is not working.

Procedure

```
PROCEDURE upsert_voucher_qualifiers (p_voucher_qualifiers_rec   IN     xxdms_voucher_qualifiers_rec,
                                        p_token                    IN     VARCHAR2,
                                        p_webservice               IN     VARCHAR2,
                                        p_user_id                  IN     VARCHAR2,
                                        p_lattitude                IN     VARCHAR2,
                                        p_longitude                IN     VARCHAR2,
                                        p_attribute1               IN     VARCHAR2,
                                        p_attribute2               IN     VARCHAR2,
                                        p_attribute3               IN     VARCHAR2,
                                        p_attribute4               IN     VARCHAR2,
                                        p_attribute5               IN     VARCHAR2,
                                        p_error_code                  OUT VARCHAR2,
                                        p_error_msg                   OUT VARCHAR2)
   IS
      lv_package_name     VARCHAR2 (100) := 'XXDMS_VOUCHER_PKG';
      lv_procedure_name   VARCHAR2 (100) := 'UPSERT_VOUCHER_QUALIFIERS';
      lv_web_error_code   VARCHAR2 (100);
      lv_web_error_msg    VARCHAR2 (2000);
   BEGIN
      --  FOR i IN p_voucher_qualifiers_tbl.FIRST ..
      --         p_voucher_qualifiers_tbl.LAST
      --  LOOP
      xxweb_access_control_pkg.application_access_allowed (p_token,
                                                           p_webservice,
                                                           p_user_id,
                                                           NULL,
                                                           NULL,
                                                           NULL,
                                                           p_lattitude,
                                                           p_longitude,
                                                           NULL,
                                                           lv_web_error_code,
                                                           lv_web_error_msg);



      IF lv_web_error_code = 'S'
      THEN
         IF p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.qualifier_id IS NOT NULL
         THEN
            UPDATE xxdms_voucher_qualifiers
               SET voucher_id = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.voucher_id,
                   qualifier_type = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.qualifier_type,
                   apply_sequence = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.apply_sequence,
                   operation = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.operation,
                   open_par = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.open_par,
                   variable = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.variable,
                   data_type = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.data_type,
                   condition = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.condition,
                   VALUE = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.VALUE,
                   close_par = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.close_par,
                   enabled_flag = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.enabled_flag,
                   attribute_category = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute_category,
                   attribute1 = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute1,
                   attribute2 = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute2,
                   attribute3 = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute3,
                   attribute4 = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute4,
                   attribute5 = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute5,
                   attribute6 = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute6,
                   attribute7 = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute7,
                   attribute8 = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute8,
                   attribute9 = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute9,
                   attribute10 = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute10,
                   attribute11 = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute11,
                   attribute12 = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute12,
                   attribute13 = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute13,
                   attribute14 = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute14,
                   attribute15 = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute15,
                   last_updated_by = fnd_global.user_id,
                   last_update_date = SYSDATE,
                   last_update_login = fnd_global.user_id
             WHERE qualifier_id = p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.qualifier_id;
         ELSE
            INSERT INTO xxdms_voucher_qualifiers (voucher_id,
                                                  qualifier_type,
                                                  qualifier_id,
                                                  apply_sequence,
                                                  operation,
                                                  open_par,
                                                  variable,
                                                  data_type,
                                                  condition,
                                                  VALUE,
                                                  close_par,
                                                  enabled_flag,
                                                  attribute_category,
                                                  attribute1,
                                                  attribute2,
                                                  attribute3,
                                                  attribute4,
                                                  attribute5,
                                                  attribute6,
                                                  attribute7,
                                                  attribute8,
                                                  attribute9,
                                                  attribute10,
                                                  attribute11,
                                                  attribute12,
                                                  attribute13,
                                                  attribute14,
                                                  attribute15,
                                                  created_by,
                                                  creation_date,
                                                  last_updated_by,
                                                  last_update_date,
                                                  last_update_login)
                 VALUES (p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.voucher_id,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.qualifier_type,
                         xxdms_voucher_qualifiers_s.NEXTVAL,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.apply_sequence,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.operation,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.open_par,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.variable,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.data_type,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.condition,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.VALUE,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.close_par,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.enabled_flag,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute_category,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute1,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute2,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute3,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute4,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute5,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute6,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute7,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute8,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute9,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute10,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute11,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute12,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute13,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute14,
                         p_voucher_qualifiers_rec.attribute15,
                         fnd_global.user_id,
                         SYSDATE,
                         fnd_global.user_id,
                         SYSDATE,
                         fnd_global.user_id);
         END IF;

         --END LOOP;

         p_error_code := 'S';
         p_error_msg := NULL;
         COMMIT;
      ELSE
         p_error_code := 'E';
         p_error_msg := 'No web access for this user';
         show_log (lv_package_name || '.' || lv_procedure_name, 'No web access for this user', NULL);
      END IF;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         p_error_code := 'E';
         p_error_msg := 'Error:' || SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 200);
         xxaac_customer_consent_pkg.show_log (lv_package_name || '.' || lv_procedure_name, p_error_msg, NULL);
   END upsert_voucher_qualifiers;
```

Node js
Below is the node js code that call the function executeProcedure.

oracleDb.js

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
const ORACLE_CLIENT_PATH = process.env.ldconfig
const ORACLE_DB_HOSTNAME = process.env.ORACLE_DB_HOSTNAME
const ORACLE_DB_PORT = process.env.ORACLE_DB_PORT
const ORACLE_SERVICE_NAME = process.env.ORACLE_SERVICE_NAME
const ORACLE_SID = process.env.ORACLE_SID
const ORACLE_USER = process.env.ORACLE_USER
const ORACLE_PASSWORD = process.env.ORACLE_PASSWORD

let conn;



exports.initializeOracleClient = async () => {
    oracledb.initOracleClient({ libDir: ORACLE_CLIENT_PATH });
    // await oracledb.createPool({
    //     user: ORACLE_USER,
    //     password: ORACLE_PASSWORD,
    //     connectString: "(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST   = " + ORACLE_DB_HOSTNAME + ")(PORT =" + ORACLE_DB_PORT + "))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME=" + ORACLE_SERVICE_NAME + ")))",
    //     poolMax: 100,
    //     poolMin: 20,
    //     poolIncrement: 5,
    //     poolTimeout: 5,
    //     poolAlias: 'voucherPool'
    // }, function (err, pool) {
    //     if (err) {
    //         console.log("ERROR---" + err)
    //         return;
    //     }
    //     else {
    //         console.log("Pool created---" + JSON.stringify(pool))
    //     }
    // });
}



exports.executeQuery = async (statement, binds) => {
    try {
        return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
            await oracledb.getConnection({
                user: ORACLE_USER,
                password: ORACLE_PASSWORD,
                connectString: "(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST   = " + ORACLE_DB_HOSTNAME + ")(PORT =" + ORACLE_DB_PORT + "))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME=" + ORACLE_SERVICE_NAME + ")))"
            }, function (err, connection) {
                // oracledb.getConnection('voucherPool', function (err, connection) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("ERROR---" + err)
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    conn = connection

                    conn.execute(statement, binds, { outFormat: oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT }, function (err, result) {
                        if (err) {

                            reject(err)
                            conn.release(function (err) {
                                console.log("completed")
                                if (err) {
                                    console.error(err.message);
                                }
                            });

                        }
                        else if (result) {

                            resolve(result)
                            conn.release(function (err) {
                                console.log("completed")
                                if (err) {
                                    console.error(err.message);
                                }
                            });

                        }

                    });
                    console.log("Connection conn:" + JSON.stringify(conn))
                    return true;

                }
            });
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("Connection Error:" + err)

    }

}
exports.executeProcedure = async (statement, binds) => {
    try {
        return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {

            console.log("binds---" + JSON.stringify(binds));
            await oracledb.getConnection({
                user: ORACLE_USER,
                password: ORACLE_PASSWORD,
                connectString: "(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST   = " + ORACLE_DB_HOSTNAME + ")(PORT =" + ORACLE_DB_PORT + "))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME=" + ORACLE_SERVICE_NAME + ")))"
            }, function (err, connection) {
                // oracledb.getConnection('voucherPool', function (err, connection) {

                if (err) {
                    console.log("ERROR---" + err)
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    conn = connection
                    conn.execute(statement, binds, { outFormat: oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT }, async function (err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            conn.release(function (err) {
                                console.log("completed")
                                if (err) {
                                    console.error(err.message);
                                }
                            })
                            //return;
                        }
                        if (result && result.outBinds.cursor) {

                            const resultSet = result.outBinds.cursor;
                            let row = await resultSet.getRows();
                            var res =
                            {
                                rows: row,
                                errorCode: result.outBinds.p_error_code,
                                errorMessage: result.outBinds.p_error_msg,
                            }
                            resolve(res);
                            await resultSet.close();
                        }
                        else if (result) {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
                            resolve(result)
                        }
                        else {
                            reject(err)
                        }



                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("Statement call:" + err)

    }

}

exports.getDbObjectClass = async (val) => {
    let connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
        user: ORACLE_USER,
        password: ORACLE_PASSWORD,
        connectString: "(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST   = " + ORACLE_DB_HOSTNAME + ")(PORT =" + ORACLE_DB_PORT + "))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME=" + ORACLE_SERVICE_NAME + ")))"
    })
    console.log("RecTypeClass")

    const RecTypeClass = await connection.getDbObjectClass(val);
    console.log("RecTypeClass" + RecTypeClass)
    return RecTypeClass

}
exports.doRelease = async () => {
    conn.release(function (err) {
        console.log("completed")
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        }
    }
    );
}
```

Procedure call

```
    const moment = require('moment')
    var oracledbConfig = require('../../../config/oracleDb');
    var oracledb = require('oracledb');
    
    const service = {
    
        getItems: async (req) => {
            try {
                return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
                 
 const result = await oracledbConfig.executeProcedure("BEGIN xxdms_voucher_pkg.upsert_voucher_qualifiers(:p_voucher_qualifiers_rec,:p_token,:p_webservice,:p_user_id,:p_lattitude,:p_longitude,:p_attribute1,:p_attribute2,:p_attribute3,:p_attribute4,:p_attribute5,:p_error_code,:p_error_msg); END;",
                        {
                            p_voucher_qualifiers_rec: {
                                dir: oracledb.BIND_IN,
                                val: {
                                    voucher_id: 123,
                                    qualifier_type: "OSS",
                                    qualifier_id: 112,
                                    apply_sequence: 1,
                                    operation: "AND",
                                    open_par: "(",
                                    variable: "TEST",
                                    data_type: "TEST",
                                    condition: "ON PARTS",
                                    VALUE: "20",
                                    close_par: ")",
                                    enabled_flag: "Y",
                                    attribute_category: null,
                                    attribute1: null,
                                    attribute2: null,
                                    attribute3: null,
                                    attribute4: null,
                                    attribute5: null,
                                    attribute6: null,
                                    attribute7: null,
                                    attribute8: null,
                                    attribute9: null,
                                    attribute10: null,
                                    attribute11: null,
                                    attribute12: null,
                                    attribute13: null,
                                    attribute14: null,
                                    attribute15: null,
                                    org_id: 21
                                },
                                type: "APPS.xxdms_voucher_qualifiers_rec"
                            },
                            p_token: req.headers.p_token,
                            p_webservice: req.headers.p_webservice,
                            p_user_id: req.headers.p_user_id,
                            p_lattitude: null,
                            p_longitude: null,
                            p_attribute1: null,
                            p_attribute2: null,
                            p_attribute3: null,
                            p_attribute4: null,
                            p_attribute5: null,
                            p_error_code: { dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.STRING, },
                            p_error_msg: { dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.STRING }
                        }, {});
                    var response =
                    {
                        validators: toCamel(result.rows),
                        statusCode: result.errorCode,
                        statusMessage: result.errorMessage,
                    }
                    resolve(response)
                });
            } catch (error) {
                throw error;
            }
        },
    };
    
    function toCamel(o) {
        var newO, origKey, newKey, value
        if (o instanceof Array) {
            return o.map(function (value) {
                if (typeof value === "object") {
                    value = toCamel(value)
                }
                return value
            })
        } else {
            newO = {}
            for (origKey in o) {
                if (o.hasOwnProperty(origKey)) {
                    newKey = (origKey.toLowerCase()).toString()
                    value = o[origKey]
                    if (value instanceof Array || (value !== null && value.constructor === Object)) {
                        value = toCamel(value)
                    }
                    newO[newKey] = value
                }
            }
        }
        return newO
    }
    
    module.exports = service;
```

I getting below error Node JS.

```
Error: NJS-012: encountered invalid bind data type in parameter 2
```

After updating the type name I am getting below error

```
Error: OCI-22303: type ""."xxdms_voucher_qualifiers_rec" not found
```

Can anyone provide me a solution.

Comment: Typically where you have `type: oracledb.OBJECT` you would use something like `type: xxdms_rec`.  Look at the various examples for collections and records in the node-oracledb documentation https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#plsqlcollections

Comment: I tried using that rec but Iam getting  OCI-22303 error.Can you please help .

Comment: Can you update your question with the SQL to create the procedure and add runnable Node.js code? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you share your mail id , I will share them with you or is there any person we can contact for support?

Comment: You can create a similar example with fake names and data and update your comment here with it.  This way everyone can benefit from the solution.

Comment: I have updated my question with procedure code and Node js code.

Comment: Your bind 'val' looks wrong.  Please review doc and examples.  Please simplify your example and make it runnable.  I don't have the same packages as you and can't run your example.  Also you should convert to the async/await style of programming instead of using callbacks.

Comment: When I try to execute https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/main/examples/plsqlrecord.js example also Iam getting error.
OCI-22303: type ""."RECTEST.RECTYPE" not found

Comment: My DB version R12.2.10 and Iam using oracle client 19 in Mac OS

Comment: I know getting started is frustrating  However with limited information it is hard for us to comment helpfully.  You really need to do some debugging and testing - what bit fails?  Does it work in SQL*Plus? etc etc.  The demo runs fine for me with 19.8 client on macOS to a 21c database.